# ReactJS & Django Cross-domain

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I am trying to connect a ReactJS app (running on localhost:1234) to a Django API HTTPS site. Although I am successfully requesting CSRF with axios (withCredentials: true), still the token is not set. Here is the response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5OSy.png)

This is my Django settings:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:1234'
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS =[
    'http://localhost:1234'
]
```

Any suggestions what I might be missing? Could it be something wrong with the browser (I am testing on Chrome)?

Answer (score 1):

With modern browsers, the only solution is to use a proxy when developing your frontend app on localhost. For React apps, this can be easily done with create-react-app by adding the proxy field in package.json